# c++ throwing every number x from an array

Tags: c++

I want to make function that throws out number x from an array and then updates size of that array (n) through reference on (n).

For example i have array a[] = 3, 4, 2, 1, 4; it's size is 5. If i choose my x element to be 4 my array should become 3, 2, 1; and it's size should be 3.

This is how my function looks, it actually removes first 4 but when it finds second 4 it changes it to 0.

```
void throwOut(int a[], int& n, int x)
{
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == x)
        {
            for (; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
            }

            a[i - 1] = 0;
            n -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is here `a[i - 1] = 0;`. Remove this line from your code, rebuild and see output.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh it still doesn't fix anything, 4 is still there.

Comment: @BrdoCZ Has been your problem solved? If still not yet, pls place a comment here.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh This code you posted down there actually works very well, except when my key element is in the first place, then it just copies the whole array. Because if i is 0, it returns 0.

Comment: @BrdoCZ But it still remove first element and decrease array size as well. All element will be move to left by 1 position. Example array is: `1, 2, 3, 1, 4`, `size = 5`. It would be `2, 3, 4, 1, 4` and `size = 3`. For array `1, 2, 3, 4` `size = 4`, the array would be `2, 3, 4, 4` and `size = 3`. In both of example above, you access your array by `size` so you won't get some last values.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh If my array is for example 8, 4, 2, 8, 0, 3 and size 6, It will just print out 8, 4, 2, 8, 0, 3 and size 6.

Comment: @BrdoCZ For example remove 8 from array, do you call `throwOut(array, size, 8)` before you print?

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh Yes I do.

Comment: @BrdoCZ I modified my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh Yeah this one works great, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int found(int array[], int size, int key);
void throwOut(int array[], int &size, int key);

int main()
{
  int array[] = {8, 4, 2, 8, 0, 3};
  int size = 6;
  int key = 8;
  throwOut(array, size, key);
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      std::cout<<array[i]<< " ";
  }
}
// This function found key in array.
// return first index where key was found.
// return -1 if key was not found.
int found(int array[], int size, int key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] == key) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// This function removes all key from array and then fix the size of array.
void throwOut(int array[], int &size, int key) {
    int f = found(array, size, key);
    if (f >= 0) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = f + 1; i < size; i++) {
            if (array[i] != key) {
                array[f] = array[i];
                f++;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }
        size -= count;
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it prints `4 2 0 3`. You can also run it here: http://cpp.sh/5gqd

Answer (score 1):

Plain arrays doesn't work like this in c++. They have a statically fixed size. The only thing you could do is swap unnecessary elements to the end, and forget about them. Or even better, you could use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 8};
int to_remove = 5;

// move elems equal to `to_remove` to the end, then remove them from v
v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), to_remove), v.end());
```